# преобразовать csv в ассоциативный массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, csv

есть node js, с его помощью запускаю консольный скрипт

```
const d3 = require("d3");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');  

d3.csv("file.csv").then(function(data) {
      console.log(data); 
});
```

получаю ошибку

```
    C:\web\site-screenshot-saver\node_modules\d3-fetch\dist\d3-fetch.js:32
    return fetch(input, init).then(responseText);
    ^

    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
        at text (C:\web\site-screenshot-saver\node_modules\d3-fetch\dist\d3-fetch.js:32:3)
        at Object.csv (C:\web\site-screenshot-saver\node_modules\d3-fetch\dist\d3-fetch.js:38:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\web\site-screenshot-saver\example.js:17:4)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Как можно преобразовать csv в ассоциативный js массив с использованием node js и консольного скрипта c библиотекой d3?

csv файл:

```
url;name
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask;url_1
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/403;url_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел ссылку как это делается без использования d3, [вот она](https://technology.amis.nl/2017/02/09/nodejs-reading-and-processing-a-delimiter-separated-file-csv/), сделал по аналогии.

Answer (score 1):

csv формат прост как пень. Можно вот так:

```
import * as FS from 'fs'

const data = {}

for (let row of FS.readFileSync("some.csv", "utf8").split("\n")){
    const [url, name] = row.split(";")
    data[url] = name
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
```